# How to solve Chrome page jumps when scrolling after click?

Tags: google-chrome, touchpad, scrolling

I'm using Chrome Version 51.0.2704.106 (64-bit) on Ubuntu 16.04 64bit on HP ZBook 15.

On **any** web page, when I scroll down (using the 2 finger scroll touchpad) click on any place on the page and try continuing scrolling downwards, the page jumps to the beginning.

Any idea how to solve this?

Found related [issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=625162).

Doesn't reproduce on Firefox.

Doesn't reproduce using an external mouse.

Comment: Posted on superuser, based on the following answer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/255886/161814

Comment: I posted this on Superuser over here initally http://superuser.com/questions/1095579/jumpy-scrolling-behavior-using-chromium-with-my-touchpad-hardware-buttons